# How to initialize Either Right to an empty value in flutter - Reloaded

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, dart-null-safety, dartz

How do I correctly initialize my `Either` object in the following code?

```dart
class JobListState extends Equatable {
  const JobListState({
    this.status = JobListStatus.initial,
    this.jobListSections = Right([]),
    this.filter,
  });

  final JobListStatus status;
  final Either<Failure, List<JobListViewmodel?>> jobListSections;
  final JobListFilter? filter;
```

A very similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67681887/how-to-initialize-either-right-to-an-empty-value-in-flutter) was answered 1,5 years ago, but this results in the error `The default value of an optional parameter must be constant.`

And I guess, if I declare `this.jobListSections = const Right([])`, I can no longer assign left.

I am assigning the initial value to create the initial state for Bloc.

Comment: If you want to have final fields and a const constructor, you will not be able to set the field to another value. Why do you want it to be final and then assign a new value? You can create another instance if you want to keep the immutable state.

Comment: Equatable requires final values to my understanding

Comment: Yes, then you need to create a new instance when changing value
You create a new instance of your object, and you pass it to a new instance of the bloc'state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your variables are `final` you can not change it directly. You can declare `copyWith` method to change your values.

```dart
class JobListState extends Equatable {
  const JobListState({
    this.status = JobListStatus.initial,
    this.jobListSections = Right([]),
    this.filter,
  });

  final JobListStatus status;
  final Either<Failure, List<JobListViewmodel?>> jobListSections;
  final JobListFilter? filter;

  JobListState copyWith({
    JobListStatus? status,
    Either<Failure, List<JobListViewmodel?>>? jobListSections,
    JobListFilter? filter
  }) {
     return JobListState(
       status: status ?? this.status,
       jobListSections: jobListSections ?? this.jobListSections,
       filter: filter ?? this.filter
     );
  }
}

// anywhere you use JobListState
var state = JobListState(); // state.jobListSections is Right([])
state = state.copyWith(jobListSections: Left(Failure())); // state.jobListSections is Left
// here you have new state that you can emit it.
```

Comment: I had a thinking error. Actually the whole thing is about `copyWith`. And you are absolutely right, when I use `copyWith` I no longer care that `Right([])` is a constant. So I can also declare it as `this.jobListSections = const Right([])`